# JQuery checkbox state not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone tell me why this line isnt working? (i'm trying to access the value property of a checkbox and write it into my variable or otherwise if its not checked an empty string)

```
var ri_ort = $('#ri_ort').attr('checked')?$('#ri_ort').val():'';
```

Thx a lot

Comment: Can you confirm which version of jQuery you are using? The method of checking a element's "checked" status changed after version 1.6 to use the prop() method instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `is`:

```
var ri_ort = $('#ri_ort').is(':checked') ? $('#ri_ort').val() : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, you can check attributes like `checked` and `disabled` using the `prop` method:

```
$('#ri_ort').prop('checked'); // returns true or false
```

`prop` also can be used to set the value:

```
$('#ri_ort').prop('checked', false); // removes the `checked` attribute
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BeKa4/1/

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.6, `attr` method doesn't return a boolean value, it returns `undefined`,  you should use `prop` or `is` method instead:

```
var $elem = $('#ri_ort');
var ri_ort = $elem.prop('checked') ? $elem.val(): '';
```

Or if you want to listen to the change event:

```
$(function() {
   var ri_ort = '';
   $('#ri_ort').change(function(){
       ri_ort = this.checked ? this.value : '';
   })
})
```